# typescript custom hook ,event type question

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello everyone i have two question

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, getData] = useGetData('posts');
  const [show, handleModal] = useHandleModal();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(show);
  }, [show]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" name="name" value="button" onClick={getData} />
      <input type="button" name="name2" value="button2" onClick={handleModal} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**error code**

```
<input type="button" name="name2" value="button2" onClick={handleModal} />
```

**error message**

```
Type 'boolean | ((e: any) => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

why onClick is error ?

I don't understand this error message

Maybe custom hook function type problem

But I don't know where to declare type

**useHandleModal.tsx(custom hook)**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleModal = useCallback(
    (e: any) => {
      setShow(!show);
    },
    [show],
  );

  return [show, handleModal];
};
```

I want use event in custom hook

I can declare any but i don't use any

Let me know event type please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are returning your variables in the hook as an array. What happens when you do this is that typescript infers the array type which in your case is `boolean | ((e: any) => void)[]` so each entry in the array has the type of `boolean | ((e: any) => void)`, which of course is not compatible with `MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>`

**There are couple of things you can do to fix the typing issue**

1. First of you can return it using an object (*and get it as an object destructuring )*:

   ```
   // in hook
   return {show, handleModal};

   // in app
   const {show, handleModal} = useHandleModal();
   ```

   In this case typescript is able to infer each of the values of the object separately and not as a whole.
2. The second thing you can do is to specifically tell typescript to treat each entry in the array as a constant (`readonly`, exact type) when you export it. And you get it the same way you have.

   ```
     return [show, handleModal] as const;
   ```

**Typing the event inside the hook**

If you want to use the event inside the hook you can use the following typing `(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>)` And you should also use the `currentTarget` instead of the `target`. I would not go in detail of what this is but I would leave you some references:

[MDN Docs on currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Based on the comment you left on this post I would want to give you an example snippet:

```
  const handleModal = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const { id } = e.currentTarget;
      
      if (id !== "modal") {
        setShow(!show);
      }
    },
    [show]
  );
```

Comment: I did this use to 'id'

This code fine ??
```
const handleModal = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
      const { id } = e.target as Element;
      if (id !== 'modal') {
        setShow(!show);
      }
    },
    [show],
  );
```

Comment: I will update my answer with the correct way of getting the event shortly

Answer (score 0):

You could check this examples about useStates types. And the most important are the examples on onClick, onChange and onSubmit

```
export interface ValidUser {
  user: UserReducedInfo,
  userFullData : User | null | undefined
}

export default function useUser (): ValidUser | null | undefined {
  const [user, setuser] = useState<UserReducedInfo | null | undefined>(null)
  const [userFullData, setuserFullData] = useState<User | null |undefined>(null)

  // more code

  return { user, userFullData }
}

 const handleClick : MouseEventHandler = () :void => {
    // Your code
  }

const handleChange: React.ChangeEventHandler = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ): void => {
    // your code
  }

const handleSubmit: 
React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
  ): void => {
    e.preventDefault()
// your code
}
```